# Custom NSSharingService for Google+

Tags: google-plus, osx-mountain-lion, appkit

I need to add Google+ as a custom NSSharingService in a Mountain Lion app.

Can anyone please refer me to the references needed for that (both of Google+ and how to write a custom NSSharingService)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the information you need to get started with the Google+ Platform can be found at https://developers.google.com/+/

Answer (score 1):

And on top of that, for an example of writing a custom NSSharingService take a look at Apple's example: http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#samplecode/SharingServices/

Comment: This custom service cannot be installed system wide. That would require installing a plugin into the system-wide sharing service, and every plugin unfortunately seems to be checked for being code-signed with Apple's own certificates.